# Laravel payment ID incorrectly stored

Tags: laravel, payment-gateway

I am integrating a payment gateway. On localhost everything works correctly, i make request to payment provider and got response with order id in return. Hover ever when i moved to live server now instead of order id such as this 3104632297 a huge negative value such as this -1190334960 is stored in DB.

for code part no big magic in there. This is the part where i update the order.:

```php
$order->update([
    'order_id' => $response->json['id'],
]);

return $response;
```

I have also debuged the values coming from the gateway and they are actually correct.

Does anyone has a clue what might be wrong? After manually changing the negative value to proper id it works so i do not get it at all.

Comment: Before update, first `dd(payment id)` and check what actual value you have

Comment: Hi, thank you for answer. Yeah I did that and it shows the proper vallue. Also proper value is dd after the order update. It is just incorectly stored in the db and i dont know why

Answer (score 1):

Please update **Type** of order_id in your table.

If you are expecting only digits then then use `Type = BIGINT` and `Attributes = UNSIGNED`. If the order_id consist of characters as well then simple `VARCHAR(40)` of a specific length will suffice.

Comment: I have tried that, however when i do it i got Numeric value out of range: 1264 Out of range value for column 'order_id' at row 1 (SQL: update `orders` set `order_id` = 3104623428, `orders`.`updated_at` = 2020-06-15 06:07:04 where `id` = 19930022) . What i found out is that if i use strval(paymentId) then correct value is stored and set column to varchar it works. i dont get it

Answer (score 0):

Just change your table column defined as `VARCHAR(as_your_id_length)`

Comment: I have tried that, however when i do it then the negative value is beign stored. What i found out is that if i use strval(paymentId) then correct value is stored.